# Is there a published numerically stable version of the Recursive Least-Squares algorithm?

Tags: optimization

I have implemented in MATLAB the recursive least-squares algorithm given in, for instance, Hayes's excellent *Statistical Digital Signal Processing and Modeling* (p. 541ff).

However, when I run the algorithm on real data with a forgetting factor $\lambda<1$ (e.g. $\lambda = 0.9$), after about 2000 updates I always reach a point where my filter coefficients explode in size and obviously overflow. Stepping through the algorithm with a debugger reveals that the coefficients of $P$, the inverse correlation matrix, grow exponentially bigger due, I believe, to the division by $\lambda$ at each timestep.

I've done a literature search but found very little useful information. I found a paper by [Bouchard](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165168402001354) who recommends to force $P$ to be symmetric, but that didn't help.

Is there a published version of the RLS algorithm that "fixes" these numerical instability problems? Or does anyone know what else I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into QR-RLS filters? I think Haykin's "Adaptive Filter theory" is the standard reference here.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds very promising. But I have no access to that book, at least not quickly. Do you know of a paper I could get hold of?

Comment: Not really.But Google is our friend. eg http://signal.hut.fi/~mobien/Thesis/QRD-RLS%20adaptive%20filter%20book/chap3.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. It'll take me a while to test this algorithm but I'm going to assume it works for me and accept your answer.

Comment: BTW: I suggest you that next time you try http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of question

Comment: Point taken. Didn't even know they had a site for that :-)